# DocuSign authentication service for applications

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on an integration with the DocuSign API. I want the users to log in to my app and then initiate the signing process from there. The users must not have a DocuSign account, they should be able to sign without log in to DocuSign. As I understand the JWT Grant flow is the best choice for this scenario by impersonating a system user and create envelopes and recipient view requests for the users who will sign. Please, correct me if I'm doing this wrong.

Many companies who offer electronic signature services also offer authentication services. For example OTP via email, SMS or some other eID. I would like that if the user could authenticate with DocuSign first before accessing my application. I haven't find a service like that at DocuSign. Is there a way to authenticate users without DocuSign accounts for my application with their service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first write:

> The users must not have a DocuSign account

You later write:

> I would like that if the user could authenticate with DocuSign first
> before accessing my application

These two statement conflict. You can only authenticate if you have an account.

However, if what you mean is just get an SMS text there are two features you can use:

1. Send with SMS - sending the SMS as the means of obtaining a signature from user. User doesn't have to have an account with DocuSign.
2. SMS authentication - envelope is sent via email, SMS is used as a second factor auth. User doesn't have to have an account with DocuSign.

JWT or Auth Code Grant can either be used for the one user/account that does have the ability to send envelopes from DocuSign. Either one would work.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to describe a lil bit more. I meant an authentication completely separate from the signing flow with e.g. email or SMS OTP. I would like the user the first sign in to my app using this auth and when the user would click the sign button in the app first then it would call the DocuSign API to create the envelope and the view request etc. So authentication with DocuSign with OTP but without an account. I'm looking for something like: https://www.signicat.com/products/authentication but with DocuSign.

Comment: Then use Auth Code Grant, and the user will have to authenticate with DocuSign

Comment: Ok, but in that case the user needs to have an account at DocuSign?

Comment: yes, correct, no other way to have a user login. If you want user to login - they have to have an account.